# Do nested convex bodies have increasing "Volume/Surface Area" ratios?

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-geometry, high-dimensional-geometry

Suppose we have two convex bodies $A$ and $B$, where $A \subseteq B$.  Is it always true that $\mathrm{Vol}(A)/\mathrm{SurfaceArea}(A) \leq \mathrm{Vol}(B)/\mathrm{SurfaceArea}(B)$?

It's true in all the examples I've tried, but I'm not sure how to prove the general case, or whether the general case is even true.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for http://mathoverflow.net/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A note: the isoperimetric constant is usually defined in a scale-invariant way, i.e. $S^{1/n-1}/V^{1/n}$, where $S$ is surface area (Hausdorff measure or Minkowski content), $V$ is volume (Lebesgue measure) and $n$ is the dimension.

Comment: cross-posted at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877183/do-nested-convex-bodies-have-nested-isoperimetric-ratios

Comment: Thanks, but the lack of scale invariance is intentional.  (The corresponding scale invariant inequality would be false.)

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.